# sveltekit app running in docker shows changes only for second

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vite, sveltekit

I have dockerized the sveltekit app and my issue is that when I am running container
and when I make changes in frontend UI I am able to see them only for 1 second and then
my frontend is looking like before any changes.
I think that problem is about caching in sveltekit.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /test-app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 24678 
CMD ["node", "build"]
```

My docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  svelte-test:
    image: sveltekit-test:node
    volumes:
      - ./:/test-app/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 24678:24678
      - 5173:5173
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Port 3000 is for sveltekit, 5173 is for sveltekit but in Docker and 24678 is for vite.
My folder structure is:

```
sveltekit-docker
    test-app
        -Dockerfile
        -docker-compose.yaml
        -package-lock.json
        -package.json
        -svelte.config.js
        -tsconfig.json
        -vite.config.js
        -all sveltekit folders (src, node_modules, static, tests)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the changes you need HMR (Hot module reloading) available in dev mode.

You also may need to rebuild `esbuild`. Try replacing the last line of your Dockerfile with

`CMD npm rebuild esbuild && npm run dev -- --host`

I created a [repo](https://github.com/fcrozatier/kit_docker) if it helps.

To use it:

```
docker build --tag sveltekit-test .
docker-compose up
```